# Can't download CSV data from AWS Athena in usable format

Tags: csv, amazon-athena

I've got 70,000+ CSV files in an S3 bucket. They all have the same headers. I would like to combine the files into one CSV, which I want to download onto my machine.

Using AWS Athena, I seem to be most of the way there. I have created a database from the S3 bucket. I can then run queries like this:

```
select * from my_table_name limit 100
```

And see the results of the query (which in my case is combining many CSVs from S3) in the Athena console.

However when I go to "Download results" of that query, I can't open the CSV in Excel (or a text editor).

Doing

```
file -b my_table_name.csv
```

returns `data`.

I'm confused because I can visually see the results of my Athena query but can't download them in a usable file format.  Am I missing something obvious for how to download this data? Why isn't it giving me a normal (perhaps UTF-8) CSV?

Answer (score 0):

In Athena settings, I had encryption on. That solved it.